# Oracle SQL Error ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00933

What is wrong with this query?

```
SELECT F.PART_NUM, F.DESCRIPTION, S.PART_NUM, S.DESCRIPTION, F.CLASS 
FROM PART F, PART S 
WHERE F.CLASS = S.CLASS AND F.PART_NUM < customer_num =" ORDERS.CUSTOMER_NUM" 
customer_name =" 'Johnson''s"> SELECT ORDERS.ORDER_NUM, ORDER_DATE
FROM ORDERS, ORDER_LINE, PART
WHERE ORDERS.ORDER_NUM = ORDER_LINE.ORDER_NUM
AND ORDER_LINE.PART_NUM = PART.PART_NUM
AND DESCRIPTION = 'Iron';
```

Comment: semi-colon `;` after `" 'Johnson''s"`

Comment: There are so many things wrong with it, that is it hard to start.  Here are some obvious ones:  not using proper `JOIN` syntax; no parentheses around the subquery; `>` that seems to be referring to two columns; double quotes around `ORDERS.CUSTOMER_NUM`.

Comment: Double quotes are for identifiers, e.g. "column-name". Use single quotes for string literals, e.g. 'Johnson''s'.

Comment: What is `customer_num =" ORDERS.CUSTOMER_NUM" customer_name =" 'Johnson''s"> SELECT ORDERS.ORDER_NUM, ORDER_DATE` supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

Difficult to provide a correct answer with table structures and an explanation of the business logic you're trying to implement but I think you want something like this:

```
SELECT F.PART_NUM, F.DESCRIPTION, S.PART_NUM, S.DESCRIPTION, F.CLASS 
FROM PART F, PART S 
     , ( SELECT customer_num
               , customer_name
               , order_line.part_num
        FROM ORDERS, ORDER_LINE 
        WHERE ORDERS.ORDER_NUM = ORDER_LINE.ORDER_NUM ) o
WHERE F.CLASS = S.CLASS 
AND F.PART_NUM < o.customer_num 
and o.customer_name ='Johnson''s'
AND o.PART_NUM = PART.PART_NUM
AND DESCRIPTION = 'Iron';
```